# Angular Testing Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Service:

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm new to testing. I have a `service` and a `spec` file that when run I get the following error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DashboardService: (?).    error
>   properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })

The `spec` file looks like this:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';

describe('The Dashboard Service', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [DashboardService, ApiService] });
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        const service: DashboardService = TestBed.get(DashboardService);
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The `service` looks like this so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';
import { Organization } from '../../models/organization';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: ApiService
})
export class DashboardService {
    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

    getPrograms(id: number): Observable<any> {
        let url  = '/apiurl' + id;
        return this.api.get<Organization>(url);
    }
}
```

So I guess the error is because of the dependencies to the `service` file but after reading the Angular documentation I'm still not sure of how to let Angular know about these dependencies. How do I structured the `spec` file to read dependencies correctly?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

First:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

then:

```
it('should be created', inject([DashboardService], (dashboardService: DashboardService) => {
  expect(dashboardService).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: Hi @Rene O - Thanks! I ended up adding `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` to the `test.ts` file and the error went away. Although I'm getting different probably non related errors now....

Answer (score 1):

For me I was using TestBed to inject a regular class and got this error.  This class was not injectable even though it was a service, we needed to have unique instances of it and that's what threw me off.  Instead just create a new instance of this class using new testClass() etc.  In my case I thought this class had an @Injectable() when it didn't

Answer (score 0):

I added `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` to `test.ts` file.